# form_for with json return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, form-for

I currently have a form like this:

```
<% form_for @stem, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :sound %>
<% end %>
```

This outputs (essentially):

```
<form method="post" id="new_stem" class="new_stem" action="/stems">
<input type="file" size="30" name="stem[sound]" id="stem_sound">
</form>
```

However I'm planning to use jQuery's ajaxForm plugin here and would like the new stem to be returned in JSON format. I know if the form's action was "/stems.json" this would work, but is there a parameter I can put into the form_for call to ask it to return JSON?

I tried doing

```
<% form_for @stem, :html => {:multipart => true, :action => '/stems.json'} do |f| %>
```

but this didn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% form_for @stem, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => "/stems.json" do |f| %>
blublublub
<% end %>
```

solves the problem

Answer (score 15):

Just specify the data-type:

```
= form_for(@stemp, :remote => true, :html => {:'data-type' => 'json', :multipart => true})
```

Answer (score 11):

even cleaner:

```
<% form_for @stem, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => stems_path(:format => "json") do |f| %>
  blublublub
<% end %>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer specifically because for some unknown reason when I was attempting to have a data-type as 'html' using a form_tag, like: `form_for(@example, :remote => true, :html => {:'data-type' => 'html'})`, it did not work, and my logger reported "**Processing by ExamplesController#index as */***" when I really wanted "**Processing by ExamplesController#index as HTML**." Your solution evaluated correctly: `<%= form_tag examples_path(:format=>'html'), :method=>:get, :remote=>true%>`